# Vim inoremap for specific filetypes

Tags: php, vim, code-completion

I've added some simple `inoremap` commands to my `.vimrc` to help with parens and brackets completion, but I only want them to apply to php files.

```
 inoremap ( ()<Esc>i
 inoremap { {<CR>}<Esc>ko
 inoremap <? <?php ?><Esc><Left>i
```

How to I set these commands to be active only when I'm editing a .php file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim: would like it to turn settings on only for certain file types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469564/vim-would-like-it-to-turn-settings-on-only-for-certain-file-types)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `autocmd FileType`:

```
autocmd FileType php,c,java inoremap ( ()<Esc>i
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to do 2 things:

- create a mapping local to a specific buffer by using the `<buffer>` option for `inoremap`.
- load the mappings for just a specific filetype.

This can be done via an autocommand in your `.vimrc` like so:

```
autocmd FileType php inoremap <buffer> ( ()<Esc>i
```

The other way option is by creating a filetype plugin. (see `:h ftplugin` for more details)

A simple example is do create a file named, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` and place your mappings inside like so:

```
inoremap <buffer> ( ()<Esc>i
inoremap <buffer> { {<CR>}<Esc>ko
inoremap <buffer> <? <?php ?><Esc><Left>i
```

I personally lean more towards the ftplugin approach but having a everything in your `.vimrc` file can be nice.

Comment: Great, only one author out of five knows about `<buffer>`.

Comment: Interestingly, the <buffer> options seems to give me an E488 Trailing characters error

Comment: @CamelBlues: Can you show me the command that breaks? Usually you get  E488 errors when you have an unnecessary `:` e.g. `autocmd FileType php :inoremap <buffer> ( ()<Esc>i`

Answer (score 6):

put them in a this file

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/php.vim
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do it, but this should work:

```
autocmd FileType php call Inoremaps()
fu! Inoremaps()
   inoremap ...
endfu
```

Answer (score 2):

Add them to the ftplugin file in the after directory:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim
```

More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478232/28071).

**Edit:** This file, and maybe even the directory, will not be there by default. You may have to make it if you don't see it there.