# How to map tab to regular space only for fortran files on vim

Tags: vim, fortran

I've switched from Emacs to Vim and when I edit fortran (`.f`) files, I'm used to hit tab on a new line. On my machine the indentation is fine, but on other machines, the indentation is off, how can I tell vim to map the tab key to a single space *only* on fortran files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim inoremap for specific filetypes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8825032/438329)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 2 things:

- create a mapping local to a specific buffer by using the `<buffer>` option for `inoremap`.
- load the mappings for just a specific filetype.

This can be done via an autocommand in your `~/.vimrc` like so:

```
augroup FortranMappings
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType fortran inoremap <buffer> <tab> <space>
augroup END
```

The other way option is by creating a filetype plugin. (see `:h ftplugin` for more details)

A simple example is do create a file named, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fortran.vim` and place your mappings inside like so:

```
inoremap <buffer> <tab> <space>
```

I personally lean more towards the ftplugin approach but having a everything in your `~/.vimrc` file can be nice.

**Conclusion**

I personally think this is an issue with your indention settings and working around it with a mapping more of a bandaid approach. There is a nice [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes that might be helpful: [Tabs and Spaces](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/) and [Whitespace preferences and filetypes](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/whitespace-preferences-and-filetypes/). Check your indention settings with the following:

```
:verbose set ts? sts? sw? et?
```

For more help see:

```
:h :map-local
:h ftplugin
:h :aug
:h :au
:h FileType
:h :set
:h 'ts'
:h 'sts'
:h 'sw'
:h 'et'
```

Answer (score 1):

To map the tab key to a single space only on fortran files (`*.f`, `*.f90`, `*.F` or `*.F90`), add the following in your `~/.vimrc`

```
function! FortranTab()
   inoremap <Tab> <Space>
endfunction
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.f,*.f90,*.F,*.F90 call FortranTab()
```

Comment: Oh no that won't do at all. 1) You are setting a *global* mapping instead of a *buffer*-local one. Please see `:h :map-local`. 2) The function is needless. 3) Probably best to use the `FileType` autocmd event. 4) You should probably wrap your auto commands in an `:augroup` and use `:autcmd!` so they can be re-`:source`'d. 5) You may want to mention using `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fortran` to put custom mappings. 6) It could be that the underlying issue could be solved with `:set expandtab` (Fortran uses `set expandtab` by default) 7) Does `:set ai` work for fortran?.