# Set vim default language when commiting with git

Tags: git, vim

I'm using `vim` as my editor in `git` on my Linux machine
(I have set it explicitly by running the command: 
`git config --global core.editor vim`).

The thing is, that each time `git` opens `vim` in order for me to enter my commit message (for example), the default language is **NOT** English (as I wish it was), yet it is Hebrew (the second language I have on my machine).

Note: When I open `vim` "directly" (for editing some text file - not via "some git" command), the default language is indeed English.

I'm using:

1) git version ***2.17.1***

2) vim version ***8.0.1453***

3) My OS is ***Ubuntu 18.04.1***

How can I fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you explicitly set the editor for git? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_basic_client_configuration  (core.editor). Otherwise it falls back to vi, which might cause your problem.

Comment: @HansHohenfeld - Yes I did.

Comment: When you execute `:!locale` in each Vim, the output should be different depending on whether you started it from within Git or not. It would be best if you'd find the source of that difference. A quick workaround would be explicitly forcing the right language (e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 vim`, either directly in `core.editor` or if that's not possible, in a `englishvim` wrapper script.

Comment: `git config core.editor 'vim -c "language messages C"'`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for, you should be able to achieve that by adding the following line to your `.vimrc` configuration file:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG,MERGE_MSG,TAG_EDITMSG language en_US.UTF-8
```

It's using the `autocmd` and the event and pattern to match to know when a commit message is being edited I have shamelessly stolen from `filetype.vim` on my system which comes with my `vim` installation and in this case sets the correct `filetype` (and with that syntax).

EDIT: As pointed out by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek). Since commit message should already be a recognized `FileType` event (after all I've copied the above line from common distro detection thereof), you can use that with `autocmd` as well:

```
au FileType gitcommit language en_EN.UTF-8
```

Comment: Note that you can also trigger things based on the chosen file type (see all the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825032/1256452).

Comment: That's at best a practical workaround. Would be much better to find the root cause of the differing language (as this only happens when Vim is launched by Git), and fix it at the source.

Comment: Indeed, I've missed that bit and (incorrectly) assumed rest of the system is also using non-English locale. I'll leave this up for now, but will have to consider a bit more, how/why would git change the env in which its `EDITOR` runs.