# How to set a different colorscheme for each file type in Vim?

Tags: vim

In ***Vim***, I want to use a different colorscheme for each file type.

*e.g.* I want to use `desert256` colorscheme for *Python* & *JavaScript* files, and use `jellybeans` colorscheme for *HTML* & *CSS* files.

---

I've tried putting the following code in my `.vimrc`, but the colorscheme change happens ***only*** when changing buffers for the first time.

*i.e.* If I open a new *Python* file, *Python*'s colorscheme is used, and when I open a new *CSS* *buffer*, indeed the colorscheme changes to *CSS*'s colorscheme. However, Changing back to *Python*'s buffer does not change the colorscheme back.

I've used `autocmd WinEnter` to try and make this rule happen when changing windows (and buffers), but it doesn't help:

```
autocmd WinEnter,FileType python,javascript colorscheme desert256
autocmd WinEnter,FileType *,html,css        colorscheme jellybeans  " This includes default filetype colorscheme.
```

---

How can I fix this? In addition, a bonus would be to not change a colorscheme when not needed - *i.e.* Changing from a *Python* to a *JavaScript* buffer won't change the colorscheme to "itself".

---

### EDIT:

If anyone's interested, [here is my `.vimrc` repo in github.com](https://github.com/oryband/dotvim). I'll update it with the solution I find here once given.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type). Solutions are the same -- ftplugin, autocmd.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've been looking for the same thing.  This inside your .vimrc works reasonably well although not perfect.

```
autocmd BufEnter * colorscheme default
autocmd BufEnter *.php colorscheme Tomorrow-Night
autocmd BufEnter *.py colorscheme Tomorrow
```

(Note if you're looking for a good dark color theme [Tomorrow-Night](https://github.com/ChrisKempson/Tomorrow-Theme) looks pretty good.  Very similar to theme used on Code Academy.)

Comment: This indeed works, but is a partial solution. For example if I use `solarized` theme, it switches to the light colorscheme instead of my default dark one. I guess if we combine your solution with calling a  custom user-defined function that should set some other stuff and then calling `colorscheme ..`, we can reach a good solution. However, I've abandoned trying to do this a long time ago, so I won't really try to. :) Thanks for your solution nonetheless!

Comment: @OryBand why did you abandon trying to do this?

Answer (score 22):

What you want are filetype plugins, rather than the `autocmd`s.  Run `help: ftplugin` in vim for more info.

From the vim help page:

> A filetype plugin is like a global plugin, except that it sets options and
>   defines mappings for the current buffer only.

In order to use filetype plugins, first put the line `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc.  Then create the folder `ftplugin` in your vim folder (on unix it's `~/.vim/`, I'm not familiar with windows).  Then create a script file for each file type you want to customize.  These files must be named a specific way.  From the vim help page:

> The generic names for the filetype plugins are:
>   ftplugin/filetype.vim
>   ftplugin/filetype_name.vim
>   ftplugin/filetype/name.vim

So, for example, if I wanted to create a script for a python file, I would have three options:

1. Create a file named python.vim in ftplugin
2. Create a file named python_whatever.vim in ftplugin
3. Create a file named whatever.vim in ftplugin/python

This script will then be loaded anytime I open a file that vim recognizes as a python file.

So, in order to accomplish what you want:

- Create a file named filetype.vim in the ftplugin directory for every filetype you want.
- In each of these files, add the line `colorscheme name_of_colorscheme`
- Add `filetype plugin on` to your vimrc.
- In order to set a default colorscheme, just set it in your vimrc file.  If I remember correctly, filetype plugins are loaded after your vimrc.

Edit:
The OP indicated that he had a good reason to avoid using the ftplugin directory.  After a bit more diggin, I found [this script.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme_to_show_where_you_are#Comments)  It can be placed in the global vimrc and seems intended to solve the same problem as the OP.

Comment: Are you sure this can't be done on my `.vimrc`? I'm using the Vundle plugin to avoid having to use plugin-specific folders.

Comment: Also, I just tried this. It doesn't work right. If I open a python file first, and a general file afterwards (e.g. my .vimrc file), the syntax isn't changed. :(

Comment: @Ory Band I found a different solution which might be what you want.  Link placed in answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried setting the example, but with no comments or anything I can't seem to get it to work. I'll post this comment there. But this, too, doesn't do what I'm looking for. Thank you very much, though. Very kind of you.

Comment: This worked fabulously for me because I have a complicated .vimrc and autocmds execute after I set up things like my status line colors so they muck everything up.  So after reading this, what I did instead was simply: `cp ~/.vimrc ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` and changed the one line I needed to change for python files and presto, problem solved.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I have a hack you may like. It is far from perfect, and it doesn't use a .vimrc, but it works for me. It requires you to type a different command to edit different files. It works using the -c parameter when you call gvim. This argument allows you to run vim commands after loading the file. Add this to your ~/.bashrc ( I guess you are using bash ) :

```
alias gpy="gvim -c 'colorscheme desert'"
alias gcs="gvim -c 'colorscheme jellybeans'"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for setting it on the command line, which is what I really wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BufWinEnter` instead of `WinEnter`, like this:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter,FileType javascript colorscheme jellybeans
```