# Possible to change length of tab depending on file extension?

Tags: vim, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type)

Hello.
So, I switch between '2' and '4' spaces for tabs very often. Usually I use 2 spaces for a tab for HTML files and 4 spaces for a tab for programming. Is there anyway to configure VIM, so it will automatically adjust depending on the file extension?
Also, how come VIM indents 8 spaces sometimes, like after I enter an open brace? I have it set to 4 spaces.
Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

```
set sw=4 ts=4 sts=4                             " Defaults: four spaces per tab "
autocmd FileType html :setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2 " Two spaces for HTML files "
```

Here are three different options: 'shiftwidth' ('sw') controls number of spaces for automatic indentation and some shifting commands (like `<<` in normal mode), 'tabstop' ('ts') controls visual length of a real tab character, you may want to leave defaults (8 visual cells), 'softtabstop' ('sts') controls what is being inserted/removed when you press `<Tab>` and `<CR>`. I suggest you either set it to the value of 'tabstop' or set it alongside with 'expandtab' because in other cases it will produce ugly tabs+spaces indentation.

Comment: Is there anyway that I add multiple file extensions that will use 2 spaces for a tab in the same line? Or, will I have to create new lines for other file extensions? I also want to include .jade files as having 2 space tabs, but I do not want to clutter my .vimrc file with multiple lines of file extensions that all have 2 spaces as tabs.

Comment: @Kelp You can delimit alternative patterns with comma, so it will look like `autocmd FileType html,xml,whatever :...`. Colon here is optional, I just thing that it makes code a bit more readable. You can also use `:h line-continuation` to move `:setlocal` on the next line after pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Type `:help syntax` in vim. This will open a help file giving an overview with subsequent pages/files showing you how to bind file extensions to syntax files where you can `:set shiftwidth=2`and `:set tabstop=2`for e. g. HTML files. I guess the syntax files of your installation are responsible for your brace indentation symptom as well.

Comment: Never use `:set` for filetype-related stuff. There is `:setlocal`.