# Change number of spaces for soft tabs in vim depending on extension

Tags: scala, vim

So I started learning Scala today and I got all my vim config files working for Scala syntax highlighting and such, but the files I downloaded (http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/getting-scala-syntax-hightlighting-to-work-in-vim/) did not seem to include the apparent Scala convention of indent by 2 spaces.

Since for my job I mostly work in C++ and Python, I currently have my `set tabstop=4`.

I've been trying to figure out how to use the `if/endif` statements for .vimrc files to do `set tabstop=2` if the extension if `*.scala`, otherwise use `tabstop=4` but  not having much luck.. help?

Thanks!

-kshot

Comment: Your question might be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012470/possible-to-change-length-of-tab-depending-on-file-extension

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type)

Comment: You know that Scala comes with a vi mode, yes? See `scala/misc/scala-tool-support/vim`.

Comment: FWIW, I use [Derek Wyatt's fork](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala) of the Scala bundle for vim, though I might switch to one of the alternatives with more recent updates.

Comment: So, I now have [my own fork](https://dcsobral@github.com/dcsobral/vim-scala.git) of the vim bundle for Scala. Limited support for compilation from vim as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set tabstop=4
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.scala set tabstop=2
```

Comment: it is actually better if you do `setlocal tabstop` instead of just `set` in the autocmd line.

Comment: @jelera the tabstop option is always local to the current buffer