# Automatic Hard vs Soft tab indentation based on type of file?

Tags: vim, tabs, vi

I'd like to default to soft tabs, indented two spaces (but hard tabs displayed as two spaces for Makefiles), and for vim to reindent appropriately on save.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "reindent appropriately on save"?

Answer (score 4):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type).  For your case, you would want this in your `.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
```

And this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/make.vim`:

```
setlocal noexpandtab
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `autocmd` for this, so it pretty much becomes a oneliner in your`.vimrc`

```
autocmd Filetype jade setlocal ts=2 sw=2 expandtab
autocmd Filetype yaml setlocal ts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

Everything else will still use the global defaults.