# Vim indentation with python getting wierd

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

```
def main():

        todo=TODO()#this line shows one tab one sublime text
        print("The indentation is not right")# THIS ONE SHOWS TWO TABS
```

I got a wierd problem, I cannot use the vim to edit my python file anymore. The indentation above is the same I have, but I said the indentation is wrong. By the way, the first line which works right was edit by another computer. I use Fedora 23 for my operating system and  default tab for vim is 8 space on any other files and just need a backspace to delete, when I create a .py file, the tab changes to 4 spaces and need backspace 4 times
now I cannot use my vim to edit the files.

Comment: Could you provide more details on your situation? and could you provide the outputs of the following? `:set tabstop`, `:set shiftwidth` , `set softtabstop`

Comment: Also are you using any plugins for python? like `python-mode` or `pyflakes` or anything?

Comment: @sudobangbang  I just checked it, all those three outputs were =8 when I created files other than .py, but they =4 when it is a .py file, my .vimrc didn't change this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna use tabs that are 8 spaces wide and one tab for each indentation level, use

```
:set tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 noexpandtab
```

or put it in your `.vimrc`

```
set tabstop=8
set softtabstop=8
set shiftwidth=8
set noexpandtab
```

For setting this preferences specifically for python, put this in your vimrc

```
autocmd Filetype python setlocal ts=8 sts=8 sw=8
```

or

```
autocmd FileType python set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=2|set expandtab
```

For more information, please read [secrets of tabs in vim](http://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html) and [indenting source code (vim wiki)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code)

You can also read about it in the good old vim documentation

```
:help tabstop
:help softtabstop
```

Comment: That really works in the vim, but when I write those in .vimrc, it doesn' work. why only .py has this problem

Comment: Are you using any vim plugins for python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type

Comment: setroubleshoot (1.1)
setuptools (18.0.1)
six (1.9.0)
slip (0.6.4)slip.dbus (0.6.4)sosreport (3.2.0a1)SSSDConfig (1.13.3)urllib3 (1.13.1)yumex-dnf (4.1.3)

Comment: No @C.Qian I was talking about vim plugins or scripts. Did you try the commands I added to my question? ` autocmd Filetype python setlocal ts=8 sts=8 sw=8`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have remove the comments and your code works, THX! By the way, I found the reason cause this problem:  Fedora 23 most recent update did makes change ,but I don't know which package did.

Comment: Maybe one of these did :vim-common                   x86_64 2:7.4.1718-1.fc23  updates           6.6 M
 vim-enhanced                 x86_64 2:7.4.1718-1.fc23  updates        1.2 M
 vim-filesystem               x86_64 2:7.4.1718-1.fc23  updates            25 k
 vim-minimal                  x86_64 2:7.4.1718-1.fc23  updates           501 k

Comment: Awesome. Delighted to know that it helped you.