# How to set tabs for text files in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to set my tab stops to 2 spaces in any text (.txt) file I edit but I haven't been able to get the hang of it.  Maybe I'm just dense.  I've read the inline docs to no avail.  I've tried reading Vim-related blog posts but it's difficult to narrow it down to this specific problem because searching for vim text tabs includes lots of stuff unrelated to text-type files.  This is what I've come up with but which doesn't work:

```
autocmd FileType txt setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

Feel free to downvote me and take away my programmer badge for asking such a stupid question, but I'm tired of banging my head against the wall on this.

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type or am I misreading the question?

Comment: @ArturKink it is not !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We all know that feeling. Your problem is a missing "**e**" in the **filetype**. Change "txt" to "**text**" and it should work.

If there was a problem in detecting the filetype of the file you can add this command to help vim on that.

```
autocmd BufEnter *.txt set filetype=text
```

***Result:***

```
autocmd BufEnter *.txt set filetype=text
autocmd FileType text setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

---

To check which type is your file you can execute this command:

```
:set filetype?
```

Comment: Yea, I did that but it doesn't work.  If I do vim -u .vimrc.new foo.txt and .vimrc.new has just the line you've shown in it, doing "set filetype?", just shows "filetype=".  Also, if I type in ":set", I don't see any of the new settings.

Comment: when puting the line in the `.vimrc` and calling `vim foo.txt` what happens ?

Comment: You should probably add `,BufNew` such that this also works on new files