# How to make vim settings be file extension specific

Tags: vim, ubuntu-18.04

Please forgive me if this has already been answered, but I am wanting to do the following within vim

```
set tabstop=2 expandtab
```

However, I only want this to apply to .c and .h files (since I also use makefiles and they need the hard tab ).

My old computer broke that I had this already in the vimrc, and any help would be appreciated

Edit: [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type) seems to have answered a similar question, but I cannot find a way to make this work for the .h files unless I am being dumb

Comment: Typically this is placed in your personal after directory (e.g. look at `:help after`).  See this post, https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/when-to-use-the-after-directory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type)

Answer (score -1):

I just didn't scroll down enough on this question: [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type)

The one that worked for me was

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile   *.c,*.h set ts=2 expandtab
```

Through the pointers in I got in the comments, I modified my solution to have the autocmd in a group and then to clear out the autocmd before running anything. leaving it as this:

```
:augroup cAndHeaderFiles
:       autocmd!
:       autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile   *.c,*.h set sts=2 sw=2 expandtab cindent
:augroup END
```

Comment: The solution using a `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` file (if you're on Linux/Unix/Mac) or `$HOME/vimfiles/after/plugin/c.vim` (on Windows) is better. Also, make sure you use `setlocal`, since you only want to affect that buffer and not change the global setting. You'll also want to set `shiftwidth=2`. And it's better to set `softtabstop=2` rather than mess with `tabstop`, ideally you'd want to leave that one at 8...

Comment: Consider reading this article that explains why auto commands should be grouped https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html

Comment: @filbranden Thank you for the pointer, I added the shiftwidth  to the line and changes ts to sts, I now remember my friend telling me to change softtabwidth now! (A much more experienced vim user)

Comment: @SergioAraujo Thank you for the link, I didn't think about potential over usage and while that wouldn't affect me here too much, I could see how as I expand my usage it will definitely have an impact