# How can I open file with modifiable on

Tags: vim

I want to open file with modifiable buffer `set noma` ON by default for this specific file.

for example something like this:

```
 vi file1.txt noma
 vi file2.txt ma   , # default
```

OR at least inside vim:

```
:tabnew file1.txt noma
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer for a specific file but I found this answer that allow to set specific parameters depending on the file type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type

Comment: afaik, if i update my vimrc, it will be global for all files I open using vim, which i don't want to happen.

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for your future questions on Vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that to your `.vimrc`, which will set the flag if the file has that name:

```
augroup ReadOnly
       autocmd!
       autocmd BufReadPost file1.txt set noma
augroup END
```

That will set it both if the file exists (`BufReadPost`).

Edit: The `view` command allows you to open a file in readonly mode.

For reference: `:help autocmd-groups` and `:help autocmd-define`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however does it mean I have to pre-define first the name of the readonly files inside the augroup? isn't there a genric way to do it?

Comment: you can use a wildcard (e.g. *.ini). But your question seems to say that you have a specific file (therefore with a specific name) that you want to always open non-modifiable. Isn't it the case?

Comment: I meant not to applied to all files and at same time not pre-defined, in other meaning, when i am opening a file for preview only w/o editing, i have to manually "set noma" inside it which is risky a little bit, so what I am looking for is an option to open file readonly from the terminal if needed, given a generic file name and generic extension.

Comment: Also you can use the command `view`, which opens a file with Vim, but in readonly mode.

Comment: `view` command is very useful, that is what I was looking for, Thanks a lot @padawin

Comment: Edited the answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`-R`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-R) command-line option to open a file in `'readonly'` mode (which includes `'nomodifiable'` and also other options that are useful when viewing files.)

```
$ vim -R file1.txt
```

The `view` command is usually available as a shortcut to `vim -R`, so this is often also possible:

```
$ view file1.txt
```

If you already have a Vim running and want to use it to open a file in read-only mode in a new tab, you can use this sequence:

```
:tab sview file1.txt
```

The `:view` command opens a file in read-only mode, the `:sview` command does so in a split and the `:tab` modifier has Vim do so in a new tab instead.