# What is the difference between these Python codes?

Tags: python

Code 1:

```
if 5 > 2:
 print ("Five is greater than two!")
```

Code 2:

```
if 5 > 2:
print ("Five is greater than two!")
```

What is the difference between these codes?

Code 1 has an extra space before print function and Code 2 doesn't have space before `print`, but when I am trying to run Code 1: it is showing "expected an indented block":

[image: 1]

Comment: indentation is important.

Comment: Same as between "Let's eat, grandma" and "Let's eat grandma": different syntax. Read [indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) in documentation.

Comment: Indentation Error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python

Comment: Indentation is necessary in Python

Comment: If you have any problem with indentations at any line of your code that will be pop up in the execution time. So if you place both code1 and code2 in same script. The indentation problem will occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike languages like C that use special tokens to define blocks (i.e., `{` and `}`), Python defines blocks by indentation. In the second snippet, the `print` statement isn't properly indented under the `if`, resulting in an empty `if` block (which is illegal in Python), and then an unrelated `print` statement.

Comment: Well said, good explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You need indentation!

Even the one space indentation isn't so good, the best is to use four:

```
if 5 > 2:
    print ("Five is greater than two!")
```

Related: [Python: using 4 spaces for indentation. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125653/python-using-4-spaces-for-indentation-why)

Comment: can you explain about indentation please

Comment: @RahulDora Check Murenik's solution