# What is wrong with the indentation in this Python code at the marked line?

Tags: python

```
def LCS(word_list1, word_list2):
    m = len(word_list1)
    n = len(word_list2)
    print m
    print n
      # An (m+1) times (n+1) matriword_list1
      C = [[0] * (n+1) for i in range(m+1)]   # IndentationError: unindent does not match          any outer indentation level
    print C
    i=0
    j=0
    for word in word_list1:
        j=0
        for word in word_list2:
        if word_list1[i-1] == word_list2[j-1]: 
            C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + 1
        else:
            C[i][j] = max(word_list1(C[i][j-1], C[i-1][j]))
        j+=1
    i+=1
    return C
```

Comment: Wow, python interpretor already answered your question "IndentationError: unindent does not match"

Comment: a good Python IDE would highlight wrong indentation while you type the code. Check out [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Comment: I spent two minutes wondering how the commented line is indented incorrectly. Geez, why did someone correct the error *in the question?* Without any notice and all?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer a question on why indentation is incorrect when the question keeps being edited and the indentation corrected.

However, I suggest you read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) before writing any more Python code and [avoid mixing tabs and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation). This would explain why you still see an `IndentationError` on line seven after you have corrected the indentation.

I also recommend that you try to run your script using the ['`-tt`' command-line option](http://www.python.org/doc/current/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t) to determine when you accidentally mix tabs and spaces. Of course any decent editor will be able to highlight tabs versus spaces (such as [Vim's `'list'` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'list')).

Comment: I ran into an issue editing a file with a different machine with different VIM settings. "list" helped me figured out that the original machine inserted tabs, but the other spaces. Setting "noexpandtab" on my new machine fixed it. Adding a vim modeline to my file helped me make sure it worked the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines

```
  C = [[0] * (n+1) for i in range(m+1)]   # IndentationError: unindent does not match          any outer indentation level
print C
```

should be indented at the same level. I.e.:

```
C = [[0] * (n+1) for i in range(m+1)]
print C
```

**Update**

Op has corrected the above problem. I checked the code and the error is elsewhere now:

```
for word in word_list2:
if word_list1[i-1] == word_list2[j-1]: 
    C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + 1
else:
    C[i][j] = max(word_list1(C[i][j-1], C[i-1][j]))
j+=1
```

Should be:

```
for word in word_list2: 
    # These lines have been indented extra.
    if word_list1[i-1] == word_list2[j-1]: 
        C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + 1
    else:
        C[i][j] = max(word_list1(C[i][j-1], C[i-1][j]))
    j+=1
```

Comment: @Aneeshia. It was not showing the same error. it was showing a _different_ error because you had two _different_ errors to begin with.

Comment: @Aneeshia: I am unable to reproduce your error. Why don't you make sure that your indentation is consistent? Use spaces everywhere or tabs everywhere but DON'T mix and match.

Answer (score 1):

I think its due use of mixed indentation - Tabs and Spaces

**Recommendation**: Use 4 spaces per indentation level,
Never mix tabs and spaces.
Maximum Line Length: 80

Check your Python - Editor's Setting,

### GEdit:

From Tools -> Preferences -> Editor -> Tab Width = 4 and use Spaces instead of Tabs

### Eclipse:

use Pydev - http://pydev.org

### VIM:

use following vim settings - for vim editor

```
:set tabstop=4 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
```