# Working on simple platform game issue with multiple side collisions

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame, collision, gravity

SO far I started out with a flat platform and my character on top.

I have implemented gravity and a jump function.

So the gravity concept works as following, continue to fall downwards until player has collided with an object below him.

So, this works when I have a flat platform under my hero, but when I want to implement a roof.
So a flat platform on top and beneath my player.

My gravity function just keeps falling. My terrain is all in a list of pygame.Rect.

My gravity function iterates through all my terrain and checks if player is above the floor object if so keep falling.

The issue I noticed is since I have object above my character it keeps on falling. I can't seem to figure a way to ignore tiles above my character and only focus on the ones underneath my player and check for collusion.

Once I figure this collusion issue I am sure I can then figure it our when jumping up and check collision with the roof and moving left and right.

Help appreciated.

edit:
terrain is a list of my objects tiles.
right now terrain only has 2 objects

```
#this is not correct way initialize just displaying my 2 object's rect
terrain = [<rect(400, 355, 50, 49)>,<rect(500, 198, 50, 49)>]

def GRAVITY(self, terrain):
    '''----------break is cutting of parsing the rest of the terrain.
    ----------Need to search through each terrain. Keep falling until collide with an object under the hero ONLY.
    '''
    for i in range(len(terrain)):
        print i
        #stop falling when colliding with object
        if terrain[i].top > self.rect.bottom:
            print 'above tile while falling'
            self.y += JUMPRATE
            break
        #continue falling if not standing on the object. Also catch when walking of an object then fall.
        elif terrain[i].top <= self.rect.bottom and not self.rect.colliderect(terrain[i]):
            print 'whoops missed tile'
            self.y +=JUMPRATE
            break
        else:
            print 'on tile'
            self.y = self.y
            break
```

This is the function that is called when player has jumped.

Comment: This is not [a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Post some code, give us an exact problem you are facing - we don't know how your code works, so how can we answer? The obvious note here, however, is [don't](https://code.google.com/p/pybox2d/) [reinvent](https://code.google.com/p/pymunk/) [the](http://pybox2d.blogspot.co.uk/) [wheel](http://pyode.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: zyeek, I've formatted your code twice now. Please make sure that when you paste code into your question that it is formatted correctly. This means that you need four _additional_ spaces in front of every line. Also, it seems like you are mixing tabs and spaces in your source code. This is a Bad Idea. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation

Comment: Um ok. I set my tab to be 4 spaces. Easier to manage and it not a huge chunk when I do need indentation.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, there is a break statement in each clause, so the loop will always run once, no matter how many `Rect` are in the list.

What you could do is use a `collided` flag and only break when a collision occurs.

```
def fall(self, terrain):
   collided = False
   for rect in terrain:
       if self.rect.colliderect(rect):
           collided = True
           break
   if not collided:
       self.y += JUMPRATE
```

If there's no collision, the character falls.  Otherwise, it doesn't move.  You'll have to add something to handle cases where it collides from the side, though.  Also, the character's feet will go through the floor slightly, so you should set the character's `rect.bottom` to the terrain's `top` once it collides.

Comment: Yes thanks you. I actually talked to a classmate who also had that same idea. Ended up checking when I collided with an object, meaning i focus on that terrain. Then determine if it is under the player if so. Stop falling.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to think about it -- isolate the collided terrain.  Anyway, glad you're on your way.