# Is 4 Whitespace indentation better than Tab space indentation?

Tags: c, whitespace

I am programming in C and wanted to use indentations to make my code readable. I have read somewhere that 4-Space indentations are better than Tab Indentation when I was using Python. Is that true? If so, why?

I just need a clarification about indentations forgive me for being a n00b.

Comment: There is no objective answer to this, so it's not a very good question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Python pep-8 strongly recommend spaces over tabs for indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation)

Comment: @unwind I forgot to change the title -_-... My real question is about indentations.

Comment: Controversial territory. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e

Comment: Everyone knows you should indent by two spaces!!! <bigger><bolder>grin</bolder></bigger>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For indentation purpose better to use spaces instead of tabs. Because tabs are treated differently by different editors. When you use tabs, different editors shows different indentation. For making your code visible in every editor in same way use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: I don't like this, why can't i see thigs the way i want? Why do you want to impose your ways on me? If i like my indentation to be 3 chars wide let me choose it that way (which editors support when using tabs). That's the argument pro tab. I personally prefer tab to indent, space to align. Its the only true way.

Comment: @RedX Well... notepad++ has tab support. But it's 4 chars wide not 3.(But I guess that could be changed)

Answer (score 1):

It's a preference thing, and as such every one has it's own. But no matter how you do it just do it consistently, do not have a mix of tabs and n-spaces so that no matter which editor you use the code looks homogeneous. Most editors can be configured to use spaces instead of tabs, so when you hit TAB it acutlay inserts the amount of spaces you have configured.