# Python unindent error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Would someone please point me to a discussion or documentation on the 'unindent' error in Python. I am using ipython notebook, 2.7 python. The right arrow test (to locate spaces and tabs) is not a good test for the notebook as every right arrow moves just one space even where I used tabs as in a def definition. I would really like to know exactly what causes these errors.
Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix spaces and tabs. [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) says to use spaces. Convert your tabs to 4 spaces (again, from [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)). Here is a [decent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation) [discussion](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk) on the thoughts behind spaces vs tabs.

> Therefore, it is generally a good idea not to mix tabs and spaces for
>   indentation. If you use tabs only or spaces only, you're fine.
>
> Furthermore, it can be a good idea to avoid tabs alltogether, because
>   the semantics of tabs are not very well-defined in the computer world,
>   and they can be displayed completely differently on different types of
>   systems and editors. Also, tabs often get destroyed or wrongly
>   converted during copy&paste operations, or when a piece of source code
>   is inserted into a web page or other kind of markup code.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Do you know an easy way to display spaces and tabs in ipython notebook?