# Need Clarification on Using OOP and DRY Method in Python

Tags: python, oop, dry

I'm trying to keep my code clean by applying OOP and DRY method; however, I found myself stuck with the following questions.

1) Since **checkremote** and **backup** method are dependent on the **sshlogin** method, is there another way to write it so that my object is fully initialized?

2) If there isn't a better way, where do I write the procedure for the PhoneBook Class to execute in the following manner (1 - checklocal, 2 - sshlogin, 3 - checkremote, 4 - backup)?  In main?

```
class PhoneBook:

    def __init__ (self, name, phone_number, birthdate, location):
        self.name = name
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        self.location = location
        self.ssh = None

    def checklocal (self):
        # Check local phonebook for existing names
        pass


    def sshlogin (self):
        # SSH into remote server


    def checkremote (self):
        # Check remote phonebook for existing names
        pass


    def backup (self):
        # Backup remote phonebook
```

Comment: Why in the world are `Add` and `Delete` classes? How is an addition or a deletion a kind of phone book?

Comment: Agreed with @kindall. They should probably be methods of the phonebook class, or standalone, generic functions.

Comment: Thanks.  I will make that change.

Comment: @kindall I have edited the question to get rid of the `Add` and `Delete` stuff. It really wasn't relevant to the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you probably want to use a context manager and the `with` keyword.

Since using a `Phonebook` object requires a "set up" phase beforehand, you want to make sure that is handled correctly every time you use it. So you would able to write code like this:

```
with Phonebook(name, phone_number, birthdate, location) as phbk: 
    #do stuff with the phonebook
    phbk.add(name, phone_number, birthdate, location)
```

All your setup phase steps - checking the local copy, connecting (and disconnecting) the ssh session, checking the remote copy, backup, etc. - would happen "behind the scenes" as part of the setup/tear down of the context manager (in other words, the `with` statement takes care of all that). This is similar to how you are supposed to use `open()`:

```
with open('myfile') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Cleanly opening and closing the file happens "behind the scenes", automagically. This is likely what you want to happen with your phonebook.

To get the context manager working, you use the python `__enter__` and `__exit__` magic methods. Might look something like this:

```
class PhoneBook:

    def __init__ (self, name, phone_number, birthdate, location):
        self.name = name
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        self.location = location
        self.ssh = None

    def sshlogin(self):
        # SSH into remote server

    def sshlogout(self):
        # SSH out of remote server

    def checklocal(self):
        # Check local phonebook for existing names
        pass        

    def checkremote (self):
        # Check remote phonebook for existing names
        pass            

    def backup (self):
        # Backup remote phonebook

    def __enter__(self):
        self.checklocal()
        self.sshlogin()
        self.checkremote()
        self.backup()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, cls, value, traceback):
        self.sshlogout()
        return False
```

As for your `Add` (and `Delete`) class, it really shouldn't be a class. It should probably either be:

- a method of the `Phonebook` class, like so:

  ```
  class Phonebook:
      def __init__(self):
          self.ssh = None
      def add(self, name, phone_number, birthdate, location):
          self.name = name
          self.phone_number = phone_number
          self.birthdate = birthdate
          self.location = location
  ```

  or
- a generic function, like so:

  ```
  def Add(phbk, name, phone_number, birthdate, location):
      # add to remote phonebook
  ```

A further point: your `Phonebook` class isn't named very well. Based on the `__init__` method, it's more of a phonebook entry. You may want to consider implementing your phonebook (as a context manager, as explained above) separately as a container of some kind to hold your entries (including the `add` and `delete` methods), and focus the `Phonebook` class you have (renamed as `Entry` or something) on being more of a phonebook `Entry` object that can be added to your new `Phonebook` object, in which case the add method might be more like this:

```
    def add(self, entry):
        try:
            self.entries.append(entry)
        except AttributeError:
            self.entries = [entry]
```

One other thing: I noticed you're using tab characters to define your classes, functions, and what not. This is [against the recommended practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation) - use 4 spaces instead.

A further suggestion: for something so simple as my suggested `Entry` class, you might just want to use a `collections.namedtuple`, like so:

```
from collections import namedtuple as nt
Entry = nt('Entry', 'name phone_number birthdate location')
```

Now you can do stuff like this:

```
e = Entry('rick', '8675309', '1/1/2001', '125 Sesame St`)
print(e.name)
```

Comment: Thanks Rick for taking the time to layout the details.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @dreamzboy No problem, but the best way to thank is by upvoting answers and accepted them (green checkmark).

Comment: @dreamzboy more on the with statement can be found [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)