# Flask:Expected an indented block

Tags: python, flask

So I am getting an error in my flask app which says:

```
File app.py, line 13
first = request.form.get('first')

IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Here is my app.py code

```
import time
import requests
import requests_cache

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first = request.form.get('first')
        url = "http://myAPIURL.com/ws/spm/search/perfid/{0}".format(first)
        response = requests.get(url)
        return jsonify(response.json())
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have checked the indentations and they seem to be fine to me,

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: @Celeo: Ok I will check this again now.

Comment: Yes , I had used space in one indentation :)

It seems I need some sleep inbetween too :P

Comment: You should use space for all your python indentation! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation for the reasoning (and arguments!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem certainly lies on mixing tabs and spaces. You should always indent using spaces and change the settings on your editor to use spaces instead of a tab character, that way your indentation will be consistent between different systems/editors.

But if you prefer to really indent your code using tabs characters, at least stick to the golden rule of *'Never mix tabs and spaces'*. Don't use both on your code as it will lead to errors and maybe unwanted behaviours (a line ends up being indented under a different block, for example)

It is also highly recommended by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use spaces. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120926/2084643) is a discussion about why it is recommended.