# Can't write new lines because of "IndentationError: unexpected indent" in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, indentation

I've read topics about this error and there were problems with wrong spaces.
In my problem aren't problems with `if x == 1 :`
I've added x = 2 below even_or_odd and it throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 16, in <module>
    from router import RouteLayer
  File "/home/pi/whatsapp-bot-seed/src/router.py", line 13, in <module>
    from views.super_kacper import SuperKacper
  File "/home/pi/whatsapp-bot-seed/src/views/super_kacper.py", line 25
    xd = 2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

#### Code

```
from utils.media_sender import UrlPrintSender
from yowsup.layers.protocol_messages.protocolentities.message_text import TextMessageProtocolEntity
import random

class SuperKacper():
    def __init__(self, interface_layer):
        self.interface_layer = interface_layer
        self.url_print_sender = UrlPrintSender(self.interface_layer)
        self.routes = [
            ("/(?P<evenOrOdd>even|odd)$", self.even_or_odd),
        ]

    def even_or_odd(self, message=None, match=None, to=None):
        is_odd = len(match.group("evenOrOdd")) % 2
        test = 2 # <<<<<<<<<< When I add someting, here test = 2
        num = random.randint(1, 10)
        if (is_odd and num % 2) or (not is_odd and not num % 2):
            return TextMessageProtocolEntity("[%d]\nYou win." % num, to=message.getFrom())
        else:
            return TextMessageProtocolEntity("[%d]\nYou lose!" % num, to=message.getFrom())
```

Comment: Your posted code seems to be indented properly. I would check the one in your python file.

Comment: Which file in my python file O.o

Comment: router.py is writed perfectly

Comment: The lines `("/(?P<evenOrOdd>even|odd)$", self.even_or_odd),` and `num = random.randint(1, 10)` uses tabs while the rest are using spaces

Comment: @jonhopkins I don't think the problem is there, but you're right as far as mixing spaces and tabs is not a good idea. Choose one and stick to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation

Comment: @Leb thanks for the link. I didn't know you can get away with mixing tabs and spaces in python

Comment: @jonhopkins no problem. I'm voting to close this because the problem can't be reproduced and SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad indentation. Delete blank space before this line and then use TAB to correct indentation. Try it :)

Comment: i dont see any blank space there O.o

Comment: just do it, as i wrote to you

Comment: I will try it when i go home :D