# When checking for availability of username, IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: django

When I try to self check if `p_username` key is available in `cleaned_data`, using following code:

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['p_username']
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists.')
    return username
```

This code is returning me.

```
def clean(self):
                   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Well if your code indentation is the same as you've shown here, you need to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) before writing a code I guess.
It says -

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Also there are already some points about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation)

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['p_username']
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists.')
    return username
```